# Error in Contract

Tags: solidity, error

I made the below line of code to throw a error on purpose for a tutorial I am doing. I think I understand why this would throw an error but just to be sure can someone explain to me why it would throw an error?

```
contract WillThrow {
    function aFunction() public pure {
        require(false, "Error message");
    }
}
```

Comment: In 2022 and later, consider using [custom errors](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/04/21/custom-errors/).

Answer (score 1):

You pass a boolean expression to the `require` function like `require(booleanExpression, stringErrorMessageIfTheExpressionTurnsOutFalse);`

So, if you pass a hardcoded `true` like this: `require(true, "This will never throw an error")`, then it will never throw an error.

If you pass a hardcoded `false` like this: `require(false, "This will always throw an error")`, then this will always throw an error.

If you pass an expression like `require(msg.value > 0, "The value should not be zero")`, then it will only throw an error if the value is 0, because we are requiring the value to be greater than 0, and if it's 0 the boolean expression will return `false`, and it would throw an error and show the error message pass as the second parameter to the `require` function.

So, in your example, it will always throw an error because you hardcoded `false`.